# Large Button with center image and text below

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to draw button that match parent and have image on center and text above, after all i got

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:center="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/button1" />
```

that let me to center text and place image on top of button, how to set it as i need.?
i dont want make custom button, if it possible in xml way

Comment: Can you post some sort of image for example!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried image button instead of a button then adding a textview below.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/text" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Adjust the bottom margin of the textview as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same thing via a relative layout also . have a relative layout , inside that have your imageview with drawable as icon launcher , set the layout gravity of that imageview as centerhorizontal|centerVertical, and have a text view inside the relativeLayout and align that to the top of the button. you can make the clickable of the relativelayout as true , so that it can work like a button . You xml may look somewhat like

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
>

<TextView android:id="@+id/top_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:alignParentTop=”true”
    android:text="@string/text"/>

<ImageView android:id="@+id/center_image"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:src="@drawable/image"
    android:layout_below=" @+id/top_text "
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also if you want to do this in a single button ,  Use the following

```
 <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:text="@String/text"
    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue, But I don't want to use Button and TextView separately. So I found this. I know I am giving solution late. But it helps you

```
<FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/next_btn_bg_rounded_corners">


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_restore_purchases"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@null"
                android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/restore"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:drawableStart="@mipmap/restore"
                android:text="@string/restore_purchases"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
        </FrameLayout>
```

[image: icon with text in center]